# Why i cant use loop with Sql ? What's better way to use for this kinda problem?

Tags: c#, sql

k i'm really new to programming and i'm learning along the way.I'm trying to do some food stock related program using visual studio c# and sql.

What this program does on the first page user put some stock info about ingredient of foods
Second page user use this ingredients to make a food definition and after that one is done
Third page user use his food definition to make a weekly plan and how much user need that food

what i cant do right now is t calculate last page as money.

this is my last page calculate button my sql table have 20 ingredient for each food and for 2 gram/piece for each ingredients.

```
 private void Hesapla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con.Open();



        double malgram1 = new double();
        double malgram2 = new double();
        double malgram3 = new double();
        double malgram4 = new double();
        double malgram5 = new double();
        double malgram6 = new double();
        double malgram7 = new double();
        double malgram8 = new double();
        double malgram9 = new double();
        double malgram10 = new double();
        double malgram11 = new double();
        double malgram12 = new double();
        double malgram13 = new double();
        double malgram14 = new double();
        double malgram15 = new double();
        double malgram16 = new double();
        double malgram17 = new double();
        double malgram18 = new double();
        double malgram19 = new double();
        double malgram20 = new double();

        int maladet1 = new int();
        int maladet2 = new int();
        int maladet3 = new int();
        int maladet4 = new int();
        int maladet5 = new int();
        int maladet6 = new int();
        int maladet7 = new int();
        int maladet8 = new int();
        int maladet9 = new int();
        int maladet10 = new int();
        int maladet11 = new int();
        int maladet12 = new int();
        int maladet13 = new int();
        int maladet14 = new int();
        int maladet15 = new int();
        int maladet16 = new int();
        int maladet17 = new int();
        int maladet18 = new int();
        int maladet19 = new int();
        int maladet20 = new int();
        object[] cb = { comboBox1.SelectedItem, comboBox2.SelectedItem };
        object[] txt = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text };
       
        foreach (object eleman in cb)
            foreach(object t in txt)
        {
            SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Select * from Yemekler where Yemekİsmi=@Yemekİsmi", con);

            SqlDataReader dr;
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Yemekİsmi",eleman);

            dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())

            {
               
                    malgram1 = Convert.ToDouble(t) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram1"];
                    malgram2 = Convert.ToDouble(t) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram2"];
                    malgram3 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram3"];
                    malgram4 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram4"];
                    malgram5 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram5"];
                    malgram6 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram6"];
                    malgram7 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram7"];
                    malgram8 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram8"];
                    malgram9 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram9"];
                    malgram10 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram10"];
                    malgram11 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram11"];
                    malgram12 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram12"];
                    malgram13 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram13"];
                    malgram14 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram14"];
                    malgram15 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram15"];
                    malgram16 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram16"];
                    malgram17 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram17"];
                    malgram18 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram18"];
                    malgram19 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram19"];
                    malgram20 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * (double)dr["MalzemeGram20"];

                    maladet1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet1"];
                    maladet2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet2"];
                    maladet3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet3"];
                    maladet4 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet4"];
                    maladet5 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet5"];
                    maladet6 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet6"];
                    maladet7 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet7"];
                    maladet8 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet8"];
                    maladet9 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet9"];
                    maladet10 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet10"];
                    maladet11 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet11"];
                    maladet12 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet12"];
                    maladet13 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet13"];
                    maladet14 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet14"];
                    maladet15 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet15"];
                    maladet16 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet16"];
                    maladet17 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet17"];
                    maladet18 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet18"];
                    maladet19 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet19"];
                    maladet20 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * (int)dr["MalzemeAdet20"];
                    MessageBox.Show(dr["Malzeme1"] + maladet1.ToString() + " Adet " + malgram1.ToString() + " Gram ");
                
            }
            dr.Close();
                
        }
        con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Used an Adapter and fill a datatable : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use lists and arrays for these kind of problems, every time the new gradient added to program, you have to change the code in this algorithm. Look for arrays and lists to store price and food data.